Expected value for boxes holding two types of objects
I'm struggling with an extension of the typical "$N$ containers, $n$ balls" problem and am hoping for some guidance as I don't know good search terms for this problem.
Say I have $N$ boxes, $c$ cats, and $d$ dogs.  My rules:

the cats can be found in any box with equal probability, as can the dogs
A box can hold no more than one cat at a time, can hold as many $d$ dogs, and can hold both a cat and dogs at the same time

Question: if I shuffle the system many, many times and count up the system, what is the average or expected number of boxes that hold both a cat and at least one dog?
Thank you for your help and/or guidance!

Linearity of Expectation works here.  You'll need to compute the probability that a chosen box passes the test.

Thanks for the help, lulu.  I posted what I think is the answer using your hint.

Can you show what attempts you have made so far, and where you are stuck ? No attempt questions are viewed unfavourably.

I made an attempt below.  I didn't know if it should be a solution or an edit to the above.  I'm new to this...I don't know how this should work!

Using lulu's comment:  this is my attempt at a solution.
Probability box $j$ DOESN'T have a cat: $P_j(n_c=0)=\frac{N-1}{N}\frac{N-2}{N}\ldots\frac{N-c}{N}=\frac{(N-1)!}{N^c(N-c-1)!}$
Probability box j DOESN'T have a dog: $P_j(n_d=0)=(\frac{N-1}{N})^d$
Probability box j has a cat AND has a dog: $P_j(n_c=0)\cdot P_j(n_d=0) = [1-\frac{(N-1)!}{N^c(N-c-1)!}][1-(\frac{N-1}{N})^d]$
There are $N$ boxes, so expected number of boxes having a cat and at least one dog is $N$ times the last line:
$$ N[1-\frac{(N-1)!}{N^c(N-c-1)!}][1-(\frac{N-1}{N})^d] $$
I checked for simple numbers by hand and it seems to work.  Thanks for the help, lulu!

Since exactly $c$ out of $N$ boxes contain a cat,  the probability that a selected box contains a cat is $\frac cN$.
